# Native Tab Bar with PhoneGap on an iOS App

Tags: ios, cordova

Is there any way to use Native Tab Bar (botton) using Phonegap on iOS App?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `NativeControls` plugin :

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/NativeControls/